# Dockerize angular with base path

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, nginx

I am trying to dockerize my angular project with base-href but after it's built and copied to Nginx it is not working. Will anyone be able to drop me some hints on what I can do? Could I set a base path to nginx.conf?

```
# base image
FROM node:14.15.4 as build
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@10.0.4

# add app
COPY . .

# generate build
RUN ng build --build-optimizer --aot --base-href=/dev/

# base image
FROM nginx:1.18.0-alpine

# overwrite default nginx website
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

# copy artifact build from the 'build environment'
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

# expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

# run nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, you have to update your nginx.conf**

Update your nginx conf like this,

```
location /dev/ {
   alias /usr/share/nginx/html;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /dev/index.html; 
}
```

Comment: when I build my angular do I still need to define the base-href?

Comment: @rosepalette Yes, You need to.

Comment: After sh into the container and change the nginx.conf.. it's still show me:                 2021/09/09 09:03:57 [error] 22#22: *1 "/usr/share/nginx/html/dev/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /dev/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:4201"

Comment: @rosepalette Did you reload the nginx after making the changes to conf file

Comment: i just restart the container.. will this work too?

Comment: yes it did thank you :)